# Save Uploaded file to path with new name,but how to get the original string file name

Tags: php, file, upload

am saving file after upload it as 19.jpg at folder called uploads
am trying to get the original file name only the name before save the file with different name 
here is the code.
any help would be great.

```
<?php
 $file_path = "uploads/";

   $file_path=$file_path.basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'],"uploads/19.jpg")){
       echo "success";
   }else{
       echo "fail";
   }
        ?>
```

Comment: Please expand your question and write normal sentences with interpunction so we can properly help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for (since your question isn't very clear), but try this:

`$original_file_name = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];`

If you want to save the file with the unique filename every time, you can do this:

`move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'],"uploads/$original_file_name")`

Hope this helps!